# Ensuring exactly N items with value X remain in an array with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming we have a document in my MongoDB collection like the following:

```js
{
  "_id": "coffee",
  "orders": [ "espresso", "cappuccino", "espresso", ... ],
}
```

How do I use a single update statement that ensures there are exactly say 2 `espresso`s in this document, without knowing how many there are to begin with?

I know that using 2 consecutive statements I can do

```
db.test.update(
  { _id: "coffee" },
  { "$pull": { "orders": "espresso" } }
);
```

followed by

```
db.test.update(
  { "_id": "coffee" },
  { "$push": { "orders": { "$each": ["espresso", "espresso"] } } }
);
```

But when combining both into a single statement, MongoDB balks with an error 40, claiming `Updating the path 'orders' would create a conflict at 'orders'` (understandable enough - how does MongoDB what to do first?).

So, how can I do the above in a single statement? Please note that since I'll be using the above in the context of a larger unordered bulk operation, combining the above in an ordered bulk operation won't work.

Thanks for your help!